# How to get distincts from a list inside a list and remove that (master)listitem?

Tags: c#, arrays, list

I have a `List<List<string>>` variable and I want to remove the `List<string>` with distincts in `string[0]`. How can I do that? Down here I show you what I'm trying to achieve.

```
    0, 1, 2,
   +--+--+--+
0, |a |34|st|
   +--+--+--+
1, |a |67|it| Delete this row because a is an duplicate.
   +--+--+--+
2, |b |89|st|
   +--+--+--+
```

Thanks,

Comment: How many rows do you think it's the max that you can have (just to see if it's viable to use memory or other object to hold the temporary data)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use LINQ to select list of sublists distinct by first item:

```
var result = listOflists.GroupBy(l => l[0])
                        .Select(g => g.First())
                        .ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `Distinct` an `IEqualityComparer<T>`, so:

```
class FirstItemComparer : IEqualityComparer<List<string>> {
    public bool Equals(List<string> a, List<string> b) {
        return a[0] == b[0];
    }

    public int GetHashCode(List<string> l) {
        return l[0].GetHashCode();
    }
}
...
items.Distinct(new FirstItemComparer())
```